Intent-based scan with Android Beacon Library
I'm trying to detect iBeacons with the Android Beacon Library while my Android application is in the killed state (doesn't appear in the task manager).
I've already managed to monitor and range iBeacon regions with foreground services and everything is working. Now, I want to try intent-based scans to detect beacons, but apparently I'm missing something to make that work. I tried to configure intent-based scans with the available reference Kotlin application, but I believe I didn't fully understand how intent-based scans work.
I report below the useful part of my code:
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    val beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
    BeaconManager.setDebug(true)

    val parser = BeaconParser().
    setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")
    parser.setHardwareAssistManufacturerCodes(arrayOf(0x004c).toIntArray())
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(
        parser)

    setupBeaconScanning()
}

fun setupBeaconScanning() {
    val beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)

    // Enable intent-based scans
    beaconManager.setIntentScanningStrategyEnabled(true)

    beaconManager.startMonitoring(region)

    val regionViewModel = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).getRegionViewModel(region)
    regionViewModel.regionState.observeForever(centralMonitoringObserver)
}

val centralMonitoringObserver = Observer<Int> { state ->
    if (state == MonitorNotifier.OUTSIDE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "outside beacon region: " + region)
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "inside beacon region: " + region)
        sendNotification()
    }
}

With this configuration, the monitoring is not working (nor when the app is in foreground, neither when the app is in the background).

As of Android 14, Samsung devices will stop intent-backed Bluetooth scans if the user kills the app by swiping it off the screen.
2024-04-14 20:05:58.646  4387-4990  BtGatt.GattService      pid-4387                             E  [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: org.altbeacon.beaconreference, scannerId: 8, reportDelayMillis=0
The scans will resume automatically when the library's "ScanJob" runs, which is scheduled to happen every 15 minutes +/- 5 minutes.  After the sequence above, you can see this happens here about six minutes later:
2024-04-14 20:11:07.541 28466-28466 BeaconManager           org.altbeacon.beaconreference        I  BeaconManager started up on pid 28466 named 'org.altbeacon.beaconreference' for application package 'org.altbeacon.beaconreference'.  isMainProcess=true
2024-04-14 20:11:07.607 28466-28466 ScanJob                 org.altbeacon.beaconreference        I  Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
2024-04-14 20:11:08.178 28466-28496 ScanHelper              org.altbeacon.beaconreference        D  beacon detected : id1: 74278bda-b644-4520-8f0c-720eaf059935 id2: 256 id3: 15187

This is actually a new run of the app, launched in the background when the 15 minute job started up.
If you want to resume detections more quickly, it is only possible by the user interacting with the app.  You may be able to send a notification to the user after the app is killed warning them they have disabled the app and asking them to re-enable it by tapping the notification (which re-launches the app and fixes the problem.)
On a related point:
As of Android 14, Samsung devices will not deliver Beacon scan results via BroadcastIntent once the screen is turned off after first app launch.  Delivery will resume as soon as the screen is illuminated again.
For apps using the Android Beacon Library and using the IntentScanStrategy, this means Samsung devices with Android 14 will not detect (briefly) between the first screen off and the next screen on operation after app launch.  It is unclear whether this is a Samsung bug or some intentional behavior.
See the related issue in the Android Beacon Library open source repo here for more info.

Thank you for your answer David. To reach my goal, I need to scan every ~10 seconds while the app is killed. Considering the fact that intent-based scan are not the best option for my case, are foreground services the only possibility or I can try something else?

Foreground services are the primary alternative but they have their own problems -- particularly severe limits on starting them from the background without a user gesture.  I suspect they will end up giving you more frequent dropouts than just accepting a 15 minute dropout when the app is killed.  You might also experiment with using Samsung Settings to remove background restrictions on the app to see if that changes this behavior.

You need to add code to get ranging updates, as monitoring APIs do not work well with the Intent Scan Strategy.  You are probably getting an entry event, then never getting an exit event (expected).
Per the docs regarding the Intent Scan Strategy:


It will not notify you when beacons disappear – your app will never get an exit region event when all beacons disappear, and when using Ranging APIs (recommended with the Intent Scan Strategy) you will simply stop getting ranging updates as soon as the last beacon disappears.


https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection_times.html

Thanks David for the rapid answer. I changed the code as you suggested and added ranging updates. I've also added this line of code before setting the intent-based scanning strategy:
beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(true).
Now the application is correctly ranging beacons while it's in foreground, but when I close the app I don't get any update. Do you have any clue why this is happening?

Try setting beaconManager.backgroundScanPeriod =1100 and beaconManager.backgeoundBetweenScanPeriod = 0.  If you do not do this then the default background scan periods apply and you only get a ranging update every 5 minutes.

Just tried, but still no results when the app is killed. Perhaps is this the case to open a GitHub issue to better investigate the problem?

Do you see background updates if you launch the app and simply turn off the screen?  Does the app have background location permission granted by the user?  (Check in Settings -> Apps -> Your app -> Permissions) When you "kill" the app how do you do so?

If I start the application and turn off the screen, I can see updates, but after something like 30s I can no longer see them. When I kill the app (by swiping up from the task manager) I don't see any notifications. I checked the app permissions and I have: location ("Allow all the time"), nearby devices and notifications.

What phone model and OS version are you running?  Can you please get a LogCat capture (with system level logs as well as your app) for 15 seconds before and after the updates stop?  On Vanilla Android (Pixel, Motorola) and many OEM flavors, these updates continue indefinitely. But some OEMs customize this behavior.

I'm running on a Samsung A52, Android 14. From the LogCat, I found the following logs that maybe can be helpful: org.altbeacon.beaconreference(state: Freezeable -> Frozen, Reason: uidIdle) and [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: org.altbeacon.beaconreference, scannerId: 10, reportDelayMillis=0. These 2 log lines occour as soon as the killed application stops detecting beacons.

I was unable to reproduce the log line problem described above on two other Samsung devices with Android 14, but I was able to reproduce something similar.  I added a second answer with details.

I was able to reproduce the message org.altbeacon.beaconreference(state: Freezeable -> Frozen, Reason: uidIdle) and [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP  on Android 14 only after killing the app.   I added a second answer with details.
